Building PyTorch: which OpenMP for ROCM?
I'm trying to build pytorch (latest main) with ROCm support in a conda environment.
ROCm is situated in /opt/rocm/, most of everything else is under the conda environment.
I create the environment like this:
conda create -n torch_rocm -c conda-forge gcc_linux-64=10.3.0 gxx_linux-64=10.3.0
conda activate torch_rocm
# ...
# these are instructed in the pytorch main readme:
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install mkl-static mkl-include

(see also this reference).
With this configuration I get three (!) different OpenMP implementations.

This is related (or not) to the mkl library?

/home/sampsa/anaconda3/envs/torch_rocm/lib/libiomp5_db.so
/home/sampsa/anaconda3/envs/torch_rocm/lib/libiomp5.a
/home/sampsa/anaconda3/envs/torch_rocm/lib/libiomp5.dbg


GCC version:

/home/sampsa/anaconda3/envs/torch_rocm/lib/libgomp.so.1.0.0


ROCm comes bundled with yet another OpenMP:

/opt/rocm/lib/llvm/lib/libomp*

I've decided to pick (3).  On the other hand, other parts of pytorch seem to use OpenMP that comes with the MKL libraries.  I've read something saying
one shouldn't "mix" different OpenMP libs in the same build or otherwise bad things will happen.
Q: Am I doing this right?
Pytorch's openmp cmake module is not able to find (3), so things must be
done very explicitly in the main CMakeLists.txt file:
set(OpenMP_C_FLAGS "-fopenmp")
set(OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS "-fopenmp")
set(OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES "omp")
set(OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES "omp")
set(OpenMP_omp_LIBRARY "/opt/rocm/lib/llvm/lib/libomp.so")

Q: I wonder if it is possible to pass these somehow to the setup.py script in the form of environmental variables.
Currently setup.py develop crashes into this:
...
-- MKLDNN_CPU_RUNTIME = OMP
CMake Deprecation Warning at third_party/ideep/mkl-dnn/-- DNNL_TARGET_ARCH: X64
-- DNNL_LIBRARY_NAME: dnnl
CMake Warning (dev) at third_party/ideep/mkl-dnn/cmake/OpenMP.cmake:55 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0144 is not set: find_package uses upper-case <PACKAGENAME>_ROOT
  variables.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0144" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Environment variable OPENMP_ROOT is set to:

    /opt/rocm/llvm

  For compatibility, find_package is ignoring the variable, but code in a
  .cmake module might still use it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/ideep/mkl-dnn/CMakeLists.txt:119 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /home/sampsa/anaconda3/envs/torch_rocm/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:441 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (OpenMP_C)
  does not match the name of the calling package (OpenMP).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:590 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  third_party/ideep/mkl-dnn/cmake/OpenMP.cmake:55 (find_package)
  third_party/ideep/mkl-dnn/CMakeLists.txt:119 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS) 
CMake Warning (dev) at /home/sampsa/anaconda3/envs/torch_rocm/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:441 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (OpenMP_CXX)
  does not match the name of the calling package (OpenMP).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:590 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  third_party/ideep/mkl-dnn/cmake/OpenMP.cmake:55 (find_package)
  third_party/ideep/mkl-dnn/CMakeLists.txt:119 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS) 
-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FOUND OpenMP_CXX_FOUND) 
CMake Error at third_party/ideep/mkl-dnn/cmake/OpenMP.cmake:111 (message):
  OpenMP library could not be found.  Proceeding might lead to highly
  sub-optimal performance.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/ideep/mkl-dnn/CMakeLists.txt:119 (include)

Found similar question in here.

libiomp5 is the implementation that comes with the intel compiler suite and is certainly related to mkl. Mixing that version with libomp might probably work most of the time. The scenario where things will break is, if different OpenMP calls end up in different OpenMP libraries. Therefore, using libomp sounds like a good plan, as it implements all functions that gcc or amd's clang would generate. Just make sure that libgomp is not loaded earlier during dynamic loading.
The cmake error log might give you some hints, why CMake could not find OpenMP. What is the compiler that CMake detected?
